# Which selenium version is compatible with Firefox ESR 45.2.0

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, mozilla

I am trying to use selenium on my system but always getting compatible error.
My Firefox version is :  Firefox ESR 45.2.0  IBMCCK - 2.2.4(CCK2)
and Selenium version I'm trying is: 2.53.0

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
1466835409717   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1466835410630   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1466835410631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1466835410634   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try Selenium version 2.53.1